# Making x-editable actually looks like 'it can be edited'

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, x-editable

I am using this [X-editable plugin](https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/). The talbe looks like:
[image]

Actually the Name, Date of Birth and all are editable when clicking on values.How can i make any user actually this can be edited. It doesn't look like it can be edited. I see some sort of dotted underline in values in the documentation. But it is not helping with the table. Is there any way of putting these values in box or something like that to look like 'it can be edited'?

```
$.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'inline';
$('.name').editable();
$('.dob').editable();
...
```

Comment: do you enclose the editable values in <a href>xxxx</a> ?

Comment: @andrew no.i can variables inside <td> `<td>{{$user->name}}</td>`

Comment: i have data-url instead.`<td>Name</td><td class="name" data-pk="<?php echo auth()->user()->id;?>" data-url="{{url('/edit/name')}}">{{$user->name}}</td><tr>`

Comment: i guess you could use css to add something like bottom border to your cell then. Other than that, if you have control over your templates, try to enclose the values in <a> tags. Gives you control with css and will underline only the editable text, not the whole cell (like the bottom border)